# When I move the screen it gets torn apart

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

So, I just added the InputHandler so I can move my screen with wasd (up,down,left,right). but when I try it my spritesheet gets torn apart and the screen does not move up or down, just diagonally (left and right works fine) and I dont know why it does this. I dont have any errors...

```
package ca.linus.game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class InputHandler implements KeyListener {

    public InputHandler(Game game) {
        game.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public class Key {
        private int numTimesPressed = 0;
        private boolean pressed = false;

        public int getNumTimesPressed() {
            return numTimesPressed;
        }

        public boolean isPressed() {
            return pressed;
        }
        public void toggle(boolean isPressed) {
            pressed = isPressed;
            if (isPressed) numTimesPressed++;
        }
    }

    public List<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>();

    public Key up = new Key();
    public Key down = new Key();
    public Key left = new Key();
    public Key right = new Key();


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), true);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        toggleKey(e.getKeyCode(), false);
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    public void toggleKey(int keyCode, boolean isPressed) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_W) {up.toggle(isPressed);}
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_S) {down.toggle(isPressed);}
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_D) {right.toggle(isPressed);}
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_A) {left.toggle(isPressed);}

    }
}
```

Here's my InputHandler file.

All help appreciated!

Comment: research *"Double Buffering"*

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Hot-link to a spite sheet.